# function always ignore the first argument?

Tags: javascript

I have a content that will show when we scroll.
when the content show, user can close it. If user choose to close it and then refresh the page. Even user scroll up the page, the content will not show up until 10 minutes.

heres my code:

```
var popUp= document.getElementById("popup");
var closePopUp= document.getElementsByClassName('popup-close');
var halfScreen= document.body.offsetHeight/2;
var showOnce = true;
var delay;

function slideUp(){
    popUp.style.maxHeight="400px";
    popUp.style.padding="10px 20px";
    popUp.style.opacity="1";
    if(popUp.className==="closed"){
        popUp.className="";
    }
}
function slideDown(){
    popUp.style.maxHeight="0";
    popUp.style.padding="0 20px";
    popUp.style.opacity="0";
    // add class  closed for cache
    if(popUp.className===""){
        popUp.className="closed";
        localStorage.setItem('closed', 'true'); //store state in localStorage
    }
}
```

I set the interval for user that close the content than refresh the page

```
// start interval
function startDelay() {
      delay = setInterval(slideUp, 1000);
}
// clear interval
function clearDelay() {
  window.clearTimeout(delay);
}

// check if cache heve  class  close
window.onload = function() {
    var closed = localStorage.getItem('closed');
    if(closed === 'true'){
        popUp.className="closed";
    }
}
```

here, I put 2 arguments for first time visit and multiple time

```
// show popup  when scroll 50%
window.onscroll = function scroll(ev) {
    // first time visited
    if ((popUp.className==="closed" && window.innerHeight+window.scrollY) >= halfScreen && showOnce){
       startDelay();
       showOnce = false; 
    }
    // same user multiple time visited the site 
    else if((popUp.className==="" && window.innerHeight+window.scrollY) >= halfScreen && showOnce){
       slideUp();      
       showOnce = false; 
    }
};

// close button when click close
for(var i = 0; i<closePopUp.length; i++){
    closePopUp[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        slideDown();
    });
}
```

when I first time open the page, the content show up, and it gets `closed` class when I choose to close the content (**it's correct**). But after I scroll to top refresh the page, its  show with interval **(correct too)**.
problem:
1.  if i **refresh not on top** of page, the content will show immediatly.
2. after i refresh and scroll and close the content. the content show again.

its like it read the function again?  please help